# How to set values in a string from Query in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I need to set variables coming from a simple query in SQL in C#.
I have the following code:

```
String _sFirstNameQuery = "";
string sql = "SELECT Firstname FROM EnrollmentDB WHERE SessionID Like 'cc7b87e4c1074d93bfad451ae10eb3b0'";
using (conn)
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
   try
   {
      conn.Open();
      _sFirstNameQuery = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
```

What I need is to set a string variable according to the query that I need. 
Can somebody help me out with it? When I debug the result is null

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlsQN.jpg)

Comment: ` _sFirstNameQuery = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` wrong way, google how to use `SqlDataReader`

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already _do set_ the `_sFirstNameQuery` to the returned string. What is the problem?

Comment: If the result is null then the problem is your query. You are using the correct method.

Comment: ExecuteScalar does not return a result set.

Comment: But `ExecuteScalar` returns the value of the first column of the first row of the result, so this code works correctly if there is a matching record.

Comment: I need to get a value which is in a table in my database, I build a simple query to get the value of one simple value, but the result is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run the query directly against your database and see if it returns anything.

Comment: If the result is `null` it means either there is no record with a `SessionID` like the one you provided or the `FirstName` column of that record is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching it correctly but you are doing something odd with the parameters. You dont have any parameters so there is no need for the @FirstName line.

```
String _sFirstNameQuery = "";
string sql = "SELECT Firstname FROM EnrollmentDB WHERE SessionID Like 'cc7b87e4c1074d93bfad451ae10eb3b0'";
using (conn)
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

   try
   {
      conn.Open();
      _sFirstNameQuery = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
```

Comment: Yes, you were right! I had to get rid of that cmd.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
   try

Comment: @lanshore don't forget to mark this as the correct answer and upvote